# Camera.PictureCallback to return captured image metadata?

Tags: android-studio, android-camera

I'm building an app that captures an image and at the same time save the coordinates and captured datetime.

Initially, I am using `LocationListener` to get the `latitude & longitude`, but I find it slows and unsafe, since user can just turn off and on the location thus saving a `0.0 value of latitude and longitude`.

So to make it easier, I thought of using the captured image's metadata instead.

I am using

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback()
```

Is it possible to get the EXIF metadata of the captured image? If so, how?

Comment: The user can also turn on or off whether their camera stores coordinates in the metadata, so reading the Exif doesn't necessarily help. You should write code to explain to the user why you need to use their private data (location) and ask their permission. You should also write code to explicitly handle bad/unavailable coordinates.

Comment: @JRI Yes, but as the description says, I don't want the user to wait for minutes until the GPS returns the correct value. and also, I can add a persistent dialog if the location service has been disabled.